# Javascript bundling and module loading

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, bundle

I've recently been thrown in to clean up a project which has like 45-50 individual `.js` javascript files. I wonder what the best approach would be to decrease the loading size of them all. Just concatenate all files into one with `npm` or `gulp`? Install some module loader? webpack?

Comment: Do all the loose js files dump into the global namespace?

Comment: Best approach to decrease loading size is to minify, modularize your scripts by taking advantage of revealing module pattern.

Answer (score 6):

If you're already concatenating, minifying, and uglifying and you don't want all the files to be loaded on all the pages due to a monolithic bundle, you might be looking for something like Webpack's [Commons Chunk Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/).

This plugin walks down the tree of dependencies for each endpoint defined in your Webpack.config file and determines which modules are required across all pages. It then breaks the code into two bundles, a "common" bundle containing the modules that every page requires, which you must load with a script tag on each page:

`<script src="commons.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

And an endpoint bundle for each individual page that you reference normally in a script tag placed after the commons script tag:

`<script src="specificpage.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

The result is that an individual page will not have to load modules that will only ever be used on other pages.

Again, this is a Webpack plugin. I don't know if this functionality is available as a Gulp plugin, because it must have knowledge of all endpoints in order to determine which dependencies are common to them all.

Answer (score 1):

I redirect you to the very good https://github.com/thedaviddias/Front-End-Checklist

In particular the following advises:

- JavaScript Inline: High You don't have any JavaScript code inline
     (mixed with your HTML code).
- Concatenation: High JavaScript files
     are concatenated.
- Minification: High JavaScript files are minified (you can add the .min suffix).

You can accomplish this with a package manager such as gulp, grunt or webpack (for the most famous ones). You just need to choose what you prefer to use.

If you consider webpack, You can start with my very simple (but understanding) starter: https://github.com/dfa1234/snippets-starter

Comment: unfortunately all boxes are checked, since im allready using gulp to concatenate, minify and uglify. i was just thinking if there where some better way of doing it since i dont want all the files to be loaded on all pages of the project.

Comment: OK, are you using module loader? I'm thinking in particular of ES6 module loader. If so, you don't have to fear to load all JS in all page, only the called module will be loaded

Answer (score 0):

There's no much thing that you can do, basically is:

- Concatenation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat
- Minification - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify

Instead of creating all those scripts, you can get something to re-use on [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/generators/), f.e. the [Fountain](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp), so it will reduce a lot of time just typing procedural code for doing the concatenation/minification.

Also if you can use some lazy load (like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or some frameworks have support to lazy load the module, like [Angular](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html)) that will improve the performance of your aplication

**EDIT:**
If you want even more performance, you can install some compression tool in your server, for example this one for NodeJS https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression

Answer (score 0):

I'm my personal opinion, if you have time, the best approach would be to read and understand the purpose of the project. Then plan a proper refactor. You are not fixing anything with concatenating, this is just a deployment step.

You should analyze which technologies are being used and if you want to maintain this code, in the long run, make a proper refactor into a much more modern stack, maybe you can take a seed project with ES6, webpack, Babel... and create a proper repository well maintained with proper modularity and dependencies resolution.

Once you have that, decreasing the load its just about adding proper tools in build time (babel, webpack, etc).

You would like to add some unit tests and continue working properly :)